# Including a file not using html include

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, include

In PHP I see a lot of including when it comes to things like word press, drupal etc.

It usually just looks like this

```
    header();
    body();
    footer();
```

I was wondering the ASP.NET / c# equivalent of this because i do not want to use the standard html include.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ASP.NET 'Master Page'. Create a page with '.master' extension You design once and include throught your site.

The aspHTML code will look like this:

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="master1.master" %>
```

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp) on how to use 'Master Pages'